# Next.js] getServerSideProps always return 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

```
/Pages
  /history
    /[hid]
      / HistoryDetailContainer.tsx
      / HistoryDetailPresenter.tsx
      / index.tsx
```

I'm rendering `/history/[hid]` Page with Container for data, Presenter for view.

But, when I try to fetch data with getServerSideProps at HistoryDetailContainer, it always passes undefined data.

here's my code.

--- Container ---

```js
const HistoryDetailContainer: NextPage<{
  ssrData: string;
}> = ({  ssrData }) => {
  console.log(`ssr - ${ssrData}`);

...
```

at the bottom, I'm calling getServerSideProps.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  try {
    const ssrData = 'SSR TEST';

    return {
      props: {
        ssrData,
      },
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.dir(e);
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
};
```

It always return undefined.

I want to receive data which is not 'undefined' from getServerSideProps.

Anyone know what the problem is?

I need you guys, thanks.

Comment: The `/history/[hid]` path will map to `/history/[hid]/index.tsx` route. To access the `HistoryDetailContainer` page component will need to use `/history/[hid]/HistoryDetailContainer` path.

Comment: is there way to use my `/history/[hid]/HistoryDetailContainer` in next config/setting? Or I must to use index.tsx for my content?

Comment: What do you mean by _"use my `/history/[hid]/HistoryDetailContainer` in next config/setting"_?

Comment: You said I need to use `/history/[hid]/HistoryDetailContainer` instead of `/history/[hid]/index.tsx`. I mean, I wanna know how to map to the `HistoryDetailContainer.tsx` instead of `/history/[hid]/index.tsx`.

Comment: Should I put everything in the index without applying the Container-Presenter pattern?

Comment: If `HistoryDetailContainer` and `HistoryDetailPresenter` are not meant to be pages, they shouldn't even be inside the `pages` folder.

Comment: thanks @juliomalves I think I can handle this problem now. I appreciate it. I'm just gonna move `HistoryDetailContainer` and `HistoryDetailPresenter` out of pages folder. thanks